# Import old version mysql database to the new version of mysql

Tags: mysql, database, import, export

I am trying to import an old MYSQL database dump of 4.1.21 version to the new MYSQL version i.e 5.6.35, but I am getting a lot of compatibility issues.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. MySQL is usually very backwards compatible, so if you're encountering problems each type requires a different strategy. A concrete example would make for a better question. Also should congratulate your database server on its 11th birthday, 4.1.21 is from July 2006.

Answer (score 0):

You should export desired parts and then import the desired parts of your database from your old   your new db . First you export what you need into a file then you can use that file to import it into the database.